# Как найти число, которое более всего ближе к оригиналу

Tags: python, логика

Имеется Django модель, в форму которой сохраняются числа пользователей.

```
class BotUser(models.Model):
    chat_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    user_nums = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

Так же есть переменная `original_number`, которая хранит в себе какое-то значение числа. 
Мне нужно взять список с числами пользоваетелей `BotUser.user_nums` и вытащить из него то число, которое больше всего ближе к `original_number`

Как я могу это сделать при помощи `Python` ? Посоветуйте какие методы или библиотеки, я не сталкивался с подобного рода задачками :)

Спасибо!

Comment: Взять именно список, или из базы данных запросить сразу нужное значение тоже сойдёт?

Comment: А вообще странная задача какая-то

Comment: Нужно чтоб было максимально похожее) Тоесть это ставки от юзеров, но т.к они точно не смогут предугадать, надо вытащить максимально близкое к оригиналу

Comment: Вытащить из заранее заготовленного списка или из базы данных?

Comment: Числа хранятся в джанговское форме ( в бд ), через QuerySet сделать список и через него как-то достать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим у нас есть искомое число `N` и список `lst`:

```
N = 28
lst = [61, 75, 38, 18, 74, 1, 23, 83, 12, 64, 40, 57, 80, 29, 27]
```

Решение:

```
In [111]: min(lst, key=lambda x: abs(N-x))
Out[111]: 29
```

Comment: Было бы эффективнее забирать из базы данных только нужное значение, а не доставать все существующие

Comment: @andreymal, конечно простенький SQL запрос будет эффективнее, но я не знаю структуру таблицы...

Answer (score 1):

Берём ближайший объект, который меньше ожидаемого (или равен ему):

```
near_left = BotUser.objects.filter(user_nums__lte=original_number)\
    .order_by('-original_number').first()
```

Берём ближайший объект, который больше ожидаемого:

```
near_right = BotUser.objects.filter(user_nums__gt=original_number)\
    .order_by('original_number').first()
```

Из этих двух выбираем тот, который ближе к нужному числу:

```
if not near_right or original_number - near_left.user_nums < near_right.user_nums - original_number:
    nearest_object = near_left
else:
    nearest_object = near_right
```

В зависимости от числа объектов, проставленных индексов, производительности ввода-вывода, фазы луны и положения звёзд на небе этот способ может оказаться быстрее или медленнее, нужно измерять в каждой конкретной ситуации. Но по крайней мере он не требует сгружать из базы данных все значения, поэтому мне кажется, что он должен быть быстрее

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное :З